# Should questions in the [work-environment] tag be migrated to Programmers?

Tags: discussion, software-engineering-se

Looking over the questions tagged [[work-environment]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/work-environment) on Stack Overflow, all but about two of the open questions seem to be regarding office environment issues.  Are these good candidates to migrate to Programmers, or would they be considered off-topic there as well?

Similarly, do the many [[career-development]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/career-development?sort=votes&pagesize=50) questions now belong on Programmers?

Comment: Well, there went all my delete votes.

Comment: ...aaaand close votes.

Comment: **Please don't vote to migrate these questions to Programmers'. I've checked and the ones I've looked at are off topic**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[work-environment]` No.

The office environment doesn't usually throw up problems that are unique (or affect only) developers.

We don't want questions like "What chair/desk/lighting should I have?"

Just close them as off topic.

`[career-development]` Maybe, but it's probably not worth it.

If there are any questions like "What language/toolkit should I learn next?". We don't want those.

Anything else might be OK, but be warned it's likely to get closed very quickly if it's not suitable.

Comment: FWIW, many of the questions tagged [work-environment] have little or nothing to do with the *physical* environment. They tend more toward "How do I deal with my co-workers?", and may or may not have any specificity to programmers.

Comment: @Shog9 - in that case they're probably duplicates, plus those sort of problems aren't unique to developers either.

Comment: @Chris: they are [*frequently-asked*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/41999/inspiring-people) on Programmers, but I wasn't sure where they stood so far as being on/off topic for the site. What's your opinion on a question [like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174627/software-architect-responsibilities) Career-related, or just general interpersonal fluff?

Comment: @Shog9 - I haven't got time to read those questions in depth but the first looks like it should be closed on Programmers' and the 2nd *might* be OK on Programmers'.

Comment: Ah, good... Already voted to close the latter, will do likewise with the former.

Comment: Great, thanks for the clarification. Like Shog9, I'd started to see career development and workplace questions be closed and moved to Programmers, but I wasn't sure if they were desired there. It sounds like the consensus is no, unless there is something about the question being asked that is unique to the programming profession.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on whether or not they're programmer-specific questions in the first place. A lot of office environment questions we see on Programmers are very general and apply to many other profession or offices.

Career-development would see more likely candidates for migration, but a lot of them would probably be closed as duplicate on the P.SE side.

Comment: Also, we've been seeing a lot of "What should I, personally, do next?" questions, which I've been voting to close as too localized.