# Automatically flag questions that get migrated and subsequently closed

Tags: feature-request, migration

This idea came up while I was discussing a wrongly migrated question with Programmers moderator [@ChrisF](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/47/chrisf).  Chris notices the following:

> There's still a significant proportion who use the migration option instead of just voting to close as off topic.

We thought it might be helpful to at least let people know when they've migrated a question inappropriately.  Can we get an automatic flag on questions that are migrated to other sites and then closed as off-topic?  Or better yet, can [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) automatically post a @comment to each user who voted to migrate (with a link to the target site's FAQ)?  Over time this should help raise enough awareness to slow down the number of questions that get migrated to the wrong sites.

Comment: related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84839/should-moving-offtopic-questions-to-other-stack-exchange-sites-cost-reputation

Comment: A big problem is that ~80% of SO users still have no idea what content is or is not on-topic on Programmers. This won't fix the root problem, it'll just prevent questions from getting migrated there at all.

Comment: @Cody: We only need to reach the ones who have enough rep to vote to migrate, not all of them.  My hope is that pointing out incorrect migrations will be enough to remind people to think before they migrate.

Comment: You mean [recently imported?](http://stackoverflow.com/tools)

Comment: @Will: That works on the receiving end, but doesn't provide any feedback to the source.

Comment: This is more or less completed. See [Kevin Montrose's description of the "migration rejection" mechanism](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126982/131713) (posted as the response to a request to allow diamond mods to reverse migrations).

Answer (score 3):

Case in point:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702332/what-are-the-roles-of-a-c-sofware-developer-migrated

How at least three people thought that migrating a question about lying to a prospective employer was a good idea I don't know.

Comment: OK, hands up - I voted for that. Yeah, the answer is obviously "don't lie" but there were two general questions in there too: how to get a programming job when you've no commercial experience and what you'd expect the roles-and-responsibilities of a programmer with two years experience to be / how to answer that at interview. Of course they're probably duplicates anyway. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Rup - Indeed the more general questions have already been asked (many times) before.